# Change font family throughout entire R Shiny App: CSS/HTML

Tags: html, css, r, fonts, shiny

Is it possible to change the default font of an entire shiny dashboard app? Including font for the sidebar, body, header, ggplots within the app, etc?

I know you can add font-family statements within each piece
( example: h2(strong(textOutput("t")), style = "font-family: 'Arial';")),
 but I want my entire app to use Arial and I don't want to have to write a line of code for every single feature. Is there a short cut?

Also, inline CSS is preferred to a separate css file if possible.

Thanks,
Sarah

**Edit:**

**Here is some of my code. Could you show me where I would put the necessary CSS?**

```
body<-dashboardBody( tags$style(".content {background-color: black;}"),
                 useShinyjs(),
                 tags$style(type='text/css', ".skin-blue .main-header .logo {background-color: #000000}" ),
                 tags$style(type='text/css', ".skin-blue .main-header .logo:hover {background-color: #000000}"),
                 tags$style(type='text/css', ".skin-blue .main-header .navbar {background-color: #000000}"),
                 tags$style(type="text/css",".shiny-output-error { visibility: hidden; }",".shiny-output-error:before { visibility: hidden; }"),
                 fluidPage(
                   img(src="img2.PNG",height="100%", width="100%",style='padding:0px;'),
                   br(),br(),
                   tabBox("Menu Database", width = 12,
                          tabPanel("Menu Database", 
                                   tabsetPanel(
                                     tabPanel("LTO Survey results",
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can put the `font-family` you want in a `body` selector

```css
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Or using the universal selector `*` will change every element

```css
* { font-family: Arial; }
```

Comment: great! Is that something I need to put in a seperate css file, or would it go in my R code somewhere?

Comment: @SarahGC you could also use the universal selector *

Comment: It can be done both ways. More details on how to edit css: https://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html

Answer (score 9):

Accepted answer of @David Kris is absolutely correct, just in case someone (like me) needs a little more elaboration.
As mentioned in his answer, **insert the code**

```
 * { font-family: "Arial"; }
```

**either in**

1. a css file ([shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html](http://shiny.rstudio.com/articles/css.html)), for those lazy (like me):

- create a folder www in your app directory,
- place bootstrap_custom.css file in it with just the code above,
- in your R code, use

```
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), dashboardSidebar(), dashboardBody(),
                  tags$head(tags$link(rel = "stylesheet", type = "text/css", href = "bootstrap_custom.css"))
```

**OR**

2. straight into your R code:

```
ui <- dashboardPage(dashboardHeader(), dashboardSidebar(), dashboardBody(),
                  tags$head(tags$style(HTML('* {font-family: "Arial"};'))))
```

Comment: When I run the last code with * I get this error: Error in tagAssert(controlbar[[2]], type = "aside", class = "control-sidebar") : Expected an object with class 'shiny.tag'...any idea why?

Comment: @H.berg Could you please provide the code (ideally minimal reproducible example) that is causing this error?
I suppose the error originates from the call of dashboardPage https://rdrr.io/cran/bs4Dash/src/R/dashboardPage.R

Answer (score 1):

Well, this isn't my favorite to do this but this will work. Pretty sure you're going to have to rock the `!important` otherwise you'll get beat out by the cascade on some elements.

Edit: Tested on a few sites to confirm. Was unable to get EVERYTHING to change without the `!important`

CSS:

```
* {
  font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important;
}
```

`*` = Match All Elements

Comment: `*` is better than `body` because it targets annoying elements like `input` and `button` which do not inherit fonts