# How to change font family of entire shiny app?

Tags: css, r, shiny

I am trying to change the font family of my entire shiny app. I found this solution

`* { font-family: Arial, sans-serif !important; }`

from this [url](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45359552/change-font-family-throughout-entire-r-shiny-app-css-html?noredirect=1&lq=1)

This is changing every font but also removing my icons.

```
dashboardSidebar(sidebarMenu(
                        menuItem("Data", tabName = "dataimport", icon = icon("folder-open"))))
```

[image]

This is how it looks now. It's not working without `!important` as mentioned in the solution above.
What can I do to fix this?

Answer (score 0):

Can you share the HTML code of the icon? It probably is a span or i tag.

Instead of adding the font-family to every single html element with *, you can add it to the body tag (see the approved answer in your link). Please don't use !important when adding the font-family when it isn't absolutely needed (information about !important in css: [What are the implications of using "!important" in CSS?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3706819/what-are-the-implications-of-using-important-in-css)).
If the icon still gets overwritten by you font, you can select the span or i tag in the css and set the font-family to the default font-family with icons.

CSS:

```
body {
  font-family: Arial;
}
```

Comment: <i class="fa-solid fa-folder-open"></i> Html code for icon. I have tried    body{
  font-family: Arial;
} and   *{
  font-family: Arial;}.    I have some shiny dashboard boxes and I was hoping to change all their titles too with this.

Comment: So what happened when you changed the css, what font-family is the title?

Can you please create a code snippet with the html code and css? Because then I could check what code overwrites the title in devtools, and find the selector specificity, so you don't have to use !important.
See this for selector specificity in CSS: [link css specificity explained](https://www.freecodecamp.org/news/what-is-css-specificity/)